# Changing class attributes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0DPd.png

Here are the classes and their relations in this test case of Black Jack.

In python IDLE I import "`BlackJackGame`" and bind "`game`" variable to "`BlackJackGame()`", and thus I have initialized a game of Black Jack.

Now what if I want to initialize many games of Black Jack, and I want the "Card" class to have different attributes in every game?

For example, in one Black Jack game, the cards would have the classic suits, such as `['Diamond', 'Club', 'Heart', 'Spade']`, and in other they would have made up suits, such as `['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4']`.

In short, how can I modify "Card" classes attributes when I'm binding `BlackJackGame()` to a variable, so that different games of Black Jack have different kinds of cards?

EDIT: I have coded a test case to show this problem in practice

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute = 'Test 1'):
        self.attribute = attribute

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.card = Card()

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, card = Card()):
        self.card = card


class MainDeck(object):
    def __init__(self, deck = Deck()):
        self.deck = deck

class BlackJackGame(object):
    def __init__(self, maindeck = MainDeck(), player = Player()):
        self.maindeck = maindeck
        self.player = player

#Initializing first game
game1 = BlackJackGame()

#We access "Card" classes that reside in "Deck" and "Player",
#to test "Card" class's variable.
print(game1.maindeck.deck.card.attribute) #Prints 'Test 1'
print(game1.player.card.attribute)   #Prints 'Test 1'

#Initializing second game, but this time so that "Card" class's
#attribute has a different value, when card is in "Deck"
game2 = BlackJackGame(maindeck = MainDeck(deck = Deck(card = Card(attribute = 'Test 2'))))

#We test if the attribute assignment works correctly
print(game2.maindeck.deck.card.attribute) #Prints 'State 2'
```

Now you see, that in the second Black Jack game, I want the `Card` to have different attribute value than in the first one, but my method of doing this is very painful to write, and it only changes the `Cards` that are in `Deck`, I want the `Card` to have different kind of attribute value in different games of Black Jack.

Comment: Will you please write what you tried ?

Comment: I know only one way, but it is very painful. For example, I can edit the "decks" attribute my "MainDeck" class has, when I initialize my game, like this: game = BlackJackGame(maindeck = Maindeck(decks = 4)). This is very painful to write, and as farther the classes are, the more painful it is, and if I want every card in my game have different attributes, I have to edit all classes that use card attributes in this way.

Comment: Your deck only has one card. Put a list of cards like I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Peter It is trivial how many cards my deck or player has, as I said, this is just to test case to see how classes work, not needed to be a working Black Jack game, that does not answer to my question. I appreciate your time, and if you need any clarification, I'm glad to provide some.

Comment: @Peter I see that you included an use case in the answer? That kind of thing is indeed what I'm looking for, but the problem is that if any other class in the game uses "Deck" class, the changes won't affect them, and if the "Deck" class is deeply nested in the code, targeting it can be a pain, isn't there any way to say that in this initialization of Black Jack, every class called "Card" has self.attribute = 'Test 2' ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Card = namedtuple('Card', 'attribute value')

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(suits, basic_card):
        '''Take list of suits'''
        self.cards = [basic_card._replace(suit=suit, value=value)
                      for value in range(1, 14)
                      for suit in suits]
```

Usage:

```
poker = BlackJackGame(Deck(suits=['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds'],
                           basic_card=Card(attribute='Test 1', value=0))

uno = BlackJackGame(Deck(suits=['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
                         basic_card=Card(attribute='Test 2', value=0)))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer my question at all, I need to assign attribute values for the "Card" class when I initialize my "BlackJackGame" class, so that different instances of the game have cards that have different attributes.

Comment: Pass the `Deck` to the `BlackJackGame`, or pass the `suits` and have the  `BlackJackGame` create the `Deck`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I don't need any real answer how to make my BlackJackGame work like a real game of Black Jack, it is only a test case to tell about the structure of my program, I just need to make "Card" classes variables to initialize with spesific attributes when I initialize "BlackJackGame" class, that is all. I'm sorry if i was not clear enough, I'm only a beginner, and this is my first question ever.

Comment: Show us some code, and what you are struggling with. Create an example as short as possible, no more than 10-15 lines.

Comment: I have now edited my post to include a test case tho show this problem in practice.